# TeamViewer type of service for headless servers

Tags: ssh, remote-access

So, we all use TeamViewer for accessing GUI based (Windows / Linux) remotely and of course, it works really well.

Any ideas of how to do the same with headless (Ubuntu) servers? I'm thinking that the headless servers would run some sort of service that connects to a central server, which I can then remote into (somehow) and then route through the central server to the remote server.

It's kinda like the server based TightVNC that was popular a view years ago, where you could host the "server" module and have all your TightVNC clients connect to that server, whilst you do the same on your client, and the server module provides a gateway through to the remote systems.  Just like TeamViewer really.

I wonder if the remote servers can connect to the (central) gateway server via SSH, I would do the same (again via SSH) but then the gateway server will provide me a "tunnel" through to the remote server.

I would of course prefer to have the remote servers have SSH ports opened through their firewall and then connect to them directly, but sometimes their IT teams don't like that. Having a server that runs a service, connects to a public server, means that the IT team will typically permit this, as the traffic is initiated internally and would be even more so agreeable to permitting it if that traffic uses an encrypted protocol.

Anyway - I just wondered if there was something out there that I could have a look at and see if it would work??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want a cloud controlled service (with serious security issues as of late), then check out the self-hostable [MeshCentral project](https://meshcentral.com/). It creates outbound tunnels that allow devices to communicate behind NAT and other networks.

Answer (score 1):

Good news! Teamviewer 11 supports headless Linux servers :)

https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/1111-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-a-Linux-system-with-no-graphical-user-interface

Comment: So it does! The only "downside" is that you have to have a TeamViewer account (they're free, but you know someone's is keeping an eye on how many computers you've got in there) but I thank you Rich for the great find.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.dwservice.net/en/
Works on RPI, Linux and Windows.Best Part is free and Support for Terminal access
not just GUI ( so works faster in slower internet ) .
Client side- > just run the script ( not need of GUI)
Remote side - > Run just browser.

[image]
[image]